# How can I backup / restore my Sql Server 2008 Database?

Tags: backup, sql-server-2008

I have a database that is around .. 20ish Gig. I need to (manually*) back up this database, 7zip the backup and then DOWNLOAD this backup from my server to my desktop. (Rinse, repeat sorta  often).

I knew that the size would be big, I split my tables into a number of `Files` and `FileGroups` :-

[image]

So the files `XWing_Boundaries` and `XWing_BoundayStreets` are (more or less) static data**. So I put those in their own file and filegroup so I don't need to back these up and download them. I only want to download (and restore locally) the dynamic data, which is the file XWing. I don't care about the log file either.

So, is there a trick so I can just backup/download/restore the single file/filegroup I need only, instead of grabbing -all- the data, each time?

Notes:

- `*` We have nightly full backups, so that's all fine / not an issue.
- `**` I manually change this data once in a blue moon. I even toyed with the idea of making these files READONLY for the suggest extra speed increase, too.

Comment: I'm not even going to lie.  I +1'd based solely on your database names and your avatar.

Comment: It's not a bad question, either :)

Comment: @Holocryptic - *wink* .. Oh! and this question is not a trap, either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can backup specific filegroups/files. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx for full details.

Backing Up Specific Files or Filegroups

```
BACKUP DATABASE database_name FILE = XWing TO <backup_device>
```

You can also add `WITH COMPRESSION` to compress the backups prior to writing to disk.

Comment: sure? there's no mention of FILEGROUPS or FILES in that sample code, above.... Maybe want to elaborate your answer using my Filenames / filegroups?

Comment: XWing is your file's logical name, which is referenced in the sample code. I didn't know the database_name, so I left "database_name" there for you to substitute in.

Comment: but would that backup your ENTIRE db? all files/filegroups?

Comment: Sorry, I just realized I left off the "FILE =" part of the syntax - I'm a dolt and it's late.

Comment: Ahh!! u've updated your post.. kewl :) that does help now! I'll give that a go.